# Comparing pandas dataframes of different length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different lengths both indexed by date. I need both dataframes to have the same dates, ie. delete the extra entries in the longest dataframe.

I have found that I can reset index and make it another another column then call that column as a pandas dataseries and compare to the other data series, giving me a pandas series with only the entries that are also in the shorter dataframe:

```
df1 = ...
df2 = ...
dfadj = df1.reset_index(['Date'])
dfstock = dfadj['Date'][dfadj['Date'].isin(dfindex['Date'])]
```

But then I would need to find the index positions from these values and in another step delete it from the longest dataframe. Am I missing a completely different approch which would be more logical and/or simple?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and then select data in `df2` by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
idx = df2.index.intersection(df1.index)
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-02-24', '2015-02-25', '2015-02-26', '2015-02-27',
               '2015-02-28', '2015-03-01', '2015-03-02', '2015-03-03',
               '2015-03-04', '2015-03-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')

print (df2.ix[idx])
             b
2015-02-24  10
2015-02-25  11
2015-02-26  12
2015-02-27  13
2015-02-28  14
2015-03-01  15
2015-03-02  16
2015-03-03  17
2015-03-04  18
2015-03-05  19
```

Another solution is use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with inner join, what is by deafult, so can be omited `how='inner'`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Sample:

```
rng1 = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24'), periods=10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng1)   
print (df1)
            a
2015-02-24  0
2015-02-25  1
2015-02-26  2
2015-02-27  3
2015-02-28  4
2015-03-01  5
2015-03-02  6
2015-03-03  7
2015-03-04  8
2015-03-05  9

rng2 = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24'), periods=20)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': range(10,30)}, index=rng2)  
print (df2)
            b
2015-02-24  10
2015-02-25  11
2015-02-26  12
2015-02-27  13
2015-02-28  14
2015-03-01  15
2015-03-02  16
2015-03-03  17
2015-03-04  18
2015-03-05  19
2015-03-06  20
2015-03-07  21
2015-03-08  22
2015-03-09  23
2015-03-10  24
2015-03-11  25
2015-03-12  26
2015-03-13  27
2015-03-14  28
2015-03-15  29
```

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print (df)
            a   b
2015-02-24  0  10
2015-02-25  1  11
2015-02-26  2  12
2015-02-27  3  13
2015-02-28  4  14
2015-03-01  5  15
2015-03-02  6  16
2015-03-03  7  17
2015-03-04  8  18
2015-03-05  9  19
```

Last if need delete some columns use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (df.drop(['a'], axis=1))
             b
2015-02-24  10
2015-02-25  11
2015-02-26  12
2015-02-27  13
2015-02-28  14
2015-03-01  15
2015-03-02  16
2015-03-03  17
2015-03-04  18
2015-03-05  19
```

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with the ix function and looking it up in the manual didn't make me understand it.

Comment: (posted last comment by accident before finishing). The 'merge' function used with respect to both indexes at the same time seems like an intuitive solution. Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that by using merge some of the column names are changed - so even by using 'drop' to remove new columns, I do not have the old ones. I will try using the .ix function

Comment: Function `ix` means select all data by index - it is same as `df.ix[idx,:]`